# Требования для Junior Java разработчика - это всерьёз?

Tags: java

В одной из крупных компаний (на ru.indeed.com) выдвинуты требования на позицию Junior Java разработчика. Хотелось бы услышать мнение это что - шутка или реально сейчас такое от джуна требовать?
....
Мы ожидаем, что Вы:

• Java SE (1.8);
• Хорошие знания Java SE (коллекции, многопоточность, garbage collector и т.д.)
• Понимание принципов ООП, методологий разработки, шаблонов проектирования
• Уверенное владение технологиями Spring, JMS, JPA, JAX-RS, JAX-WS
• Core: Spring Framework (IoC, Security, Batch, и т . д .);
• Data: JPA / JDBC / Hibernate
• Messaging: ActiveMQ (DEV) / IBM WebSphere MQ (PROD);
• End-points: JAX-WS/ JAX-RS;
• Container: Eclipse Jetty (DEV) / WildFly / IBM WebSphere Application Server (PROD).

Data store:

• Oracle DB
• HDFS

Tools:

• CI: Jenkins;
• Issue tracking/Wiki: Jira / Confluence;
• VCS: Git / Bitbucket"
• Опыт работы с IBM WebSphere Application Server, WildFly, Jetty
• Опыт работы Linux
• Опыт работы Docker, Kubernetes, OpenShift
• Знание Oracle / SQL
• Умение пользоваться JIRA, Confluence, Git, Maven, Jenkins
• Приветствуется знание groovy, jython, bash
• Приветствуется знание front-end технологий (react, redux, webpack, typescript)

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Требования позожи на обычную копипасту, одно и то же несколько раз требуется. А вообще каждый работодатель по своему выставлят требования. И по своему проводит собеседование.

Comment: Конечно, это личное дело работодателя. Ну, т.е. в общем объёме это нормальные, средние требования для junior-a?

Comment: тут нет конкретных требований. Понимание приципов ООП - это что значит? Хорошие знания многопоточности - это как понимать? Умение пользваться JIRA - это что означает? Вы это все узнаете только на собеседовании.

Comment: Ну, про ООП это понятно, а насчет конкретных - список довольно конкретный... я всё-же про позицию Junior. Не многовато-ли? "...уверенное владение технологиями Spring, JMS, JPA, JAX-RS, JAX-WS • Core: Spring Framework (IoC, Security, Batch, и т . д .); • Data: JPA / JDBC / Hibernate • Messaging: ActiveMQ (DEV) / IBM WebSphere MQ (PROD); • End-points: JAX-WS/ JAX-RS; • Container: Eclipse Jetty (DEV) / WildFly / IBM WebSphere Application Server (PROD)."

Comment: Список конкретный, неконкретны требования. Что значит Spring? Spring большой, кго всего никто не знает поди. Что значит JIRA? Способность тикет создать или способность аддоны писать под неё? Что значит JDBC? Это все просто набор слов откуда то, это не позоже на конкретные требования. Это как знать "дзюдо", "карате" и много других иностранных слов.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что этот вопрос по работе.

Answer (score 2):

Требование к кандидатам сугубо личное требования работодателя к соискателю. На счёт реально вы видите требование. Обычно такие "жёсткие" требования выставляются с целью отфильтровать количество соискателей и не тратить время/деньги на пустые разговоры. (Это как шопинг есть деньги могу выбирать, не факт что заплачу, ширпотреб не предлагать.)

Comment: Согласен насчет "жесткого" отбора, но на позицию джуна по-моему уж слишком жёстко. Приходит на indeed парень только из универа работу искать, а там такой списочек... на зарплату джуна...

Comment: Поймите работадателю нужен Джун, тот который может что-то сделать сам и не тратить время попросту более дорогих специалистов. Нужен тот который может с небольшого пинка сделать не самую сложную работу вот кто Джун.

Comment: Абсолютно согласен, но что тогда выдвинут на мидла, вот что интересно... )))

Comment: Мидле должен самостоятельно сделать небольшой проект по всем текущим каконам. Примерно тоже самое что и вы только с учётом SOLID, patterns и прочего

Comment: Это понятно, но посмотрите весь список технологий - это ли реально от джуниора такое требовать? Где он такого опыта наберется и наоборот - если такое требуют, может хоть не джуниора позицию выставлять? В смысле - ну должны же быть реалии какие-то...

Comment: Требования что б знал как пользоваться. У компании свой стек технологий заниматься обучением бизнес не любит. Учеба это к другим, а им нужен человек который будет приносить прибыль.

Comment: Это политика данной компании. Поверьте у всех они различные.

Comment: Хотел бы я себе спеца с таким стеком технологий на зарплату джуна )))

Comment: С чего вы взяли что у них зарплата Джуна меньше вашего Мидла или Сеньёра? Это тоже их личная политика

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111773/discussion-between-inwar2006-and-aziz-umarov).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно понимать что джун джуну рознь. Вы можете быть в одной компании уверенным мидлом, но придти в другую и там вы будете джуном. Есть уровень компании и чем он выше тем выше требования. Есть разные уровни ЗП для джунов. Условно в одной компании джуну без опыта в Москве платят 50 тыс, а в другой 95, но только вот требования разные.

Второй момент нужно понимать, что это некий фильтр на смелость. Вы глянули на требования и решили, что это слишком - вы не подходите. Другой с такими же знаниями глянул и решил попробовать и прошел собес, потому что в нем увидели потенциал и желание идти вперед.

Когда я искал свою первую работу 4/5 приглашений на собес прилетали с вакансий мидла. И пришел я в итоге в компанию которая искала мидла.

Второй момент нужно понимать, что никто никому ничего не должен. Работодатель ищет себе специалиста с определенными знаниями и ценой, это его условия. Если он за N знаний даст малую сумму он будет искать дольше, если за эти же знания даст больше денег, то специалист найдется быстрее. Но это его выбор.

Comment: Я помню мне прилетел стек по типу такого. Я спросил что им всё это нужно. Ответили да на что я спроси их надеюсь что у вас ВСЕ деньги раз вы ВСЁ хотите? :)